# Repository Pattern using EF7

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a new web application using ASP.Net 5 / EF7.

I am also considering the Repository Pattern along with Entity Framework.

I am looking for some advice to deal with my generic repository class. As EF7 has no Find() method to yet, I am having some difficulties implementing the method like GetById(int id) in my generic repository class. I know that can use FirstOrDefault() instead, but I do not have access to the actual 'Id' from the model.

Can you please help me to find an alternative?

Below is my generic repository class:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly PersonDBContext _dbContext;

    public Repository(PersonDBContext context)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public TEntity Get(int? id)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

Thanks
Saeed

Comment: Is there some common property/field on `TEntity` that can be referenced. Can you show what `TEntity` look like.

Comment: TEntity will be a model later on when I am passing it to the repository class. This is the generic repository class. in this case the TEntity will be the model called e.g. Person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can try.

Based on your comment that you don't know the actual id of the model then use an expression like you did with the `Find` to get the entity you are looking for.

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>  where TEntity :  class {
    //.....

    public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }

   //.....
}
```

Comment: That's a good approach, Thanks. But, do you think this is the efficient method as I am going to have many models (Code First from database) and all have to be derived from this interface?

Comment: In that case you could use the expression route and take the first result. I'll edit answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks very much for you advice. Yes you right, I have used this technique for Find() as there is no find really in EF7 and I did not realise that I could use the same method implementation for GetById() as well. Thanks again for your help

Comment: No problem. glad to help. If this solves your problem don't forget to mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a post in my blog that explains how to create a generic repository, you can check it at [Generic Repository using EntityFramework](http://haithamshaddad.com/2016/03/11/building-a-lob-application-with-mvc-5-part-2-models-and-generic-repository/)

You Will have to add another parameter to your generic interface, instead of having only the Entity Type, you can pass also the Primary Key type and also you can use a base class

Comment: Thanks my friend, your idea is also clever. I have had a look and made some notes. Thanks very much.